# get full git history up to certain date

Tags: git

I have a git repo whose full history I want to pass onto a client, but only up to the date for which they've paid.

I kind of want the opposite of a shallow clone. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: So you want a history from the beginning up until a cutoff date, which may be earlier than right now?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's correct.

Comment: And one more question: You want to actually send the client such code?  Or just a log?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Full code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking out the latest commit occurring *before* the cutoff date:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2016-01-01 00:00" master`
```

Then create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b master_for_client
```

You can now ship this branch to your client.

Comment: but how do I ship just that branch (with full history)?

Comment: Why do you want to ship the full history?  Typically, if you want your customers to see the history, you should use a tool like GitHub or Bitbucket, which were designed for handling this.  If you just want to ship an older version, then send a build of the source files occurring before your cutoff date.

Comment: You've just changed the question :) the client owns the code, but only up to the point they paid. Therefore, they want the full history.

Comment: I would manage their branch from GitHub, Bitbucket, or a similar tool.  Make public the branch for which they have paid (up until a cutoff date).  They can do whatever they want with that branch.

Comment: I don’t know about your clients, but the clients I work for pay for the final code, not all intermediary steps. So they should be fine with just the final version imo.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty Git repository (`git init --bare`), and then push the history you want to it:

```
git push /path/to/new/repo <commit-id>:refs/heads/master
```

Then, `cd` to this repository and repack it (not strictly needed, but may help):

```
git gc --prune=now
```

To double-check: go to the new repository and check that you don't have any other branches (you won't if you applied the recipe above, but just in case):

```
git for-each-ref
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do:

Create a tag (or branch) of the latest (=newest) commit that you want to give the client:

`git tag mytag [commit_hash]`

Then use **[git bundle](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html)**, and run:

`git bundle create mybundle mytag`

Now you will have a bundle file (named **mybundle**) with all history up to your tag. Give this file to the customer.

The customer should copy **mybundle** into an empty dir, and run:
`git init`,
`git fetch mybundle mytag` and 
`git tag his_tag FETCH_HEAD`. Now he will have a git repository with tag named **his_tag** showing the required history.